# How does Redux make the component re-rendering minimal?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is an advanced question about React / Redux.

It seems I can make every component of my app base on one context (as context consumers), and use that context as the one and only data store.  But then when context changes, every single component of my app will get re-rendered -- and that is not desirable.

1) When I use the React and Redux to do the job instead, so that each component is re-rendered as little as possible, by using `connect()` and getting the Redux store data as `props`, in the React Developer Tool, there is also a `Context.Provider` but I don't see a `Context.Consumer` -- why is there no `Context.Consumer` -- how can the components get the data if there is no context consumer?

2) Does Redux somehow just add the so-called "Connect" HOC (higher order component), and add the `props` to our components, so our components are re-rendered when the props change?  But I thought our components are under this "global Redux context" too, so when the global Redux context change, why wouldn't it cause our component to re-render?  Is it by making `Connect` as a context consumer but our component not as context consumer, but just get the "props"?

3) I thought there is a rule: when `state` or `props` change, the component and the whole subtree will re-render.  What about context? Is it slightly different?  That is, when context changes, then only the components that are context consumers will re-render, but if there are offsprings in this subtree that are not context consumers, will *not* re-render?  Otherwise, how could Redux help minimize the re-rendering? If Redux store context changes, and all subtree components are re-rendered, then it is just the same as using a vanilla context and let all components be consumers.

4) But maybe (3) above is not correct... the context consumers and the whole subtree is re-rendered... just somehow, the `Connect` HOC is able to be not a context consumer but can get Redux store's state -- in fact, there is no `Context.Consumer` whatsoever in the React tool -- how does it work?

5) Maybe I found part of the answer: I kept seeing `Memo` and `Context.Provider`... in the React / Redux way. Is the `Memo` the way to "stop" the re-rendering from "going down the subtree"? And then the `Context.Provider` together with the `Memo` is like a `Connect` HOC, to provide the component with `props`... but how does this `Connect` HOC get the Redux state if it is a `Memo`? (as in `React.memo()` memoized component)? If it is the dev build instead of the production build, then the `Memo` is the `ConnectFunction`, and the `Context.Provider` is under it, and then our "connected" component is under it.

6) By the way, I am not sure if it is done by `shouldComponentUpdate()()`: when it returns false, the whole subtree is not re-rendered, but if the component observes on the Redux store (using `store.subsribe()`), and change the props to the child (our connected component), then it looks like this is how Redux can work internally. Alternatively, [if the Connect component just inherits from PureComponent, then the `shouldComponentUpdate()` just shallow compares the state and props and returns false](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation) if it is just the context change. That will also cause the whole subtree not to re-render. I think it is more like: if the context change affects the connected component down below, then return `true` for `shouldComponentUpdate()`, and pass in the proper props for the connected component. Otherwise, return `false` and leave the connected component alone.

The re-render here doesn't mean updating the actual DOM. It merely means calling the `render()` of class components or calling the function component to get the virtual DOM tree, in order to be conciliated with the previous virtual DOM tree to find the diffs and if any, update the actual DOM.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Redux itself doesn't have any React bindings, so I'm assuming you're referring to React Redux. If not, you'll need to reimplement any optimizations yourself.

> It seems I can make every component of my app base on one context (as context consumers), and use that context as the one and only data store.

Keep in mind that contexts are not data stores, they're just ways of passing down data to child components without using props. It's more of a transport layer.

> But then when context changes, every single component of my app will get re-rendered -- and that is not desirable.

If you're using raw context, you should be moving context consumers as deep down as you need them so your context updates don't cause as many unnecessary rerenders (if that's an issue in the first place, remember not to prematurely optimize).

1. Newer versions of React Redux use the `useContext` hook instead of `Context.Consumer`, which does not create the extra React element ([source](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/043517ecb989fce61ff090d89286288783f1f310/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L294)). Basically, the `useContext` hook itself is the context consumer, getting store information from the context provider.
2. By default, `connect` will automatically prevent rerenders when the Redux state updates if they don't affect the connected component's props or the result of `mapStateToProps`.
3. Updating a context provider will force its consumers to rerender, but not necessarily the components in between or the children of the context consumer users.
4. It is a context consumer (see answer #1).
5. `memo` is the new way to prevent rerenders on function components, but if you have class components you may want to use `PureComponent` or `shouldComponentUpdate` instead. It is not an alternative to `connect`, it's just part of React, and you can use it with `connect` or the newer `useSelector` hook if you want to.